# Passing data with model that gets submitted via POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, view, model

So on the view, we have quite a few objects that are mapping text boxes to send data to the model for use in the controller like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FilesAsString, new {@class = "form-control", type = "number"})
```

Pretty standard stuff.

How can I include other properties of this model that should be set in the view before the POST action? (It would be something the user cannot see and cannot edit).

For example, I would want to pass the current user data that is stores in Session["_User"] into the model that has the property x.CurrentUser.

I feel like I am overthinking this, but I don't know.

Comment: If it's on the view, the user can see it and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized how stupid my question is.

I have a `Session["_User"]` Object- this will be accessible by the controller. I just need to use `Session["_User"]` in the Controller.

I need a break...

**EDIT**: *I am leaving my question and answer in hopes that it may help some other sleep deprived developer.*

Comment: For those that want to use this behavior for a multi-page form, a hidden input might be preferable if security is not a concern.

Otherwise, TempData is ideal, as values auto-clear once read from (TempData.Peek(key) can be used for validating data without clearing it). The auto-clearing of TempData has two benefits that can be really useful:

1. You don't have to manually clear data once it is not needed anymore.
2. If there's an (accidental) bug, such as a double-submit issue, the data in TempData will only be accessible once, and an exception will be thrown, as is appropriate for a bug.

Comment: I was originally thinking about using a hidden input. Using that would inherently work, but I knew it wouldn't be the best option- security wise.
And yes, I think TempData would work in this case, though in my mind I was thinking more along the lines of something that would be bound to the model that is being posted (and would have to be accessed by the overload) similar to the hidden input but less visible.